# Where do I find the block id for Twig Tweak module

Tags: theming

In order to print a block in a twig file when using the Twig Tweak module you require the block id, but nothing I am trying will work and I get the message that -

This block is broken or missing. You may be missing content or you might need to enable the original module.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are using Twig tweak 2.x the following drush command is suggested by the [cheat sheet](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/modules/twig-tweak/cheat-sheet-8x-2x) page.

```
drush ev "print_r(array_keys(\Drupal::service('plugin.manager.block')->getDefinitions()));"
```

Answer (score 2):

I think your block id is a machine name of a block that you added here: Admin > Structure > Block layout (/admin/structure/block).

When you edit some block you will see the machine name. Besides, a disabled block is also allowed.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can enable the debug mode for twig template, and then inspect the element. There are in comments with all the id of all the HTML elements. 
Check [this](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming/twig/debugging-twig-templates)

You enable Twig Debugging in `sites/default/services.yml`.
(If `services.yml` does not yet exist; copy `default.services.yml` and copy it to `services.yml.`)

Set the debug variable to true. And clear cache.

```
parameters:
  twig.config:
    debug: true
```

Comment: Thanks for this, but I have already got this debug mode working. And can not see anything specifically that states a block id, only template suggestions and the html id of the block, which I have tried also replacing the hyphens with underscores

Comment: What about this [link](https://www.drupal.org/project/twig_tweak/issues/2924449)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, [block can mean a few things](https://www.drupal.org/docs/contributed-modules/twig-tweak/rendering-blocks-with-twig-tweak) in the context of Drupal.

For the Twig Tweak module to render a block you need the numeric id of the block (most of the time - see above link). Navigate to `/admin/structure/block/block-content`. Edit the block you want. You can see the numeric block id in a couple places on the page but I like to look in the address bar (e.g. site.com/block/5). In this example the block id is `5`.

So to render the block put the following in your twig template:

```
{{ drupal_entity('block_content', 5) }}
```

Alex Kuzava is kind of correct. That is the machine name of the block once it is placed in the block layout.

As a note there are a couple other ways to reference the block via twig tweak from the above reference link (e.g. by UUID).